# Camparing keys and values in two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function with two arrays i want to compare. Both arrays contains the same data structure but could have different values as it represents the ID's and values of the HTML form. However i only want to check objects that has the `ID/Key` of "textarea´1", "textarea2" and "textarea3" and check if their values differ in newVals and oldVals.

How can i archive this?

```
function CheckTextChange() {        
    var formData = $.parseJSON(data);
    var dbData = $.parseJSON(oldData);

    var newVals = formData[0].texts[0];
    var oldVals = dbData[0].texts[0];
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information, how are the objects build?

Comment: write a loop which goes through the keys of oldVals. keeping a reference to the key in oldVals makes things easier. check same key in newVals. if different, then you can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

heres a `compareKeys` function that takes an array of key names and two objects and returns an array of keys that have different values in both objects:

```
function compareKeys( keynames, objA, objB ){
   var diffs = keynames.filter(function( key ){
      if( key in objA && key in objB ){
        return objA[ key ] != objB[ key ];
      }
      return true; // mismatch if key doesn't exist in any object
   });
   return diffs;
}

function CheckTextChange() {        
    var formData = $.parseJSON(data);
    var dbData = $.parseJSON(oldData);

    var diffs = compareKeys( ["textarea1", "textarea2" ], formData, dbData );
    if( diffs.length > 0 ){
       console.log( "Keys %s don't match", diffs.join() );
    }
}
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfnnsL6e/)